# Shuffle a foreach loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a list of ten test questions and I'm trying to shuffle out four out of the ten questions to each students, I used the foreach shuffle and i used take(4). It's working, but the options of the questions is also changing position and scattering when picked, I also tried random(4), which also exhibit same thing. Any fix to this. Below is the code.

```
@foreach ($lesson->test->questions->shuffle()->take(4) as $question)
                <b>{{ $loop->iteration }}. {{ $question->question }}</b>
                <br />
                @foreach ($question->options as $option)
                    <input type="radio" wire:model='question.{{ $question->id }}'
                        name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]" value="{{ $option->id }}" />
                    {{ $option->option_text }}<br />
                @endforeach
                <br />
            @endforeach
```

The random process

```
@foreach ($lesson->test->questions->random(4) as $question)
                <b>{{ $loop->iteration }}. {{ $question->question }}</b>
                <br />
                @foreach ($question->options as $option)
                    <input type="radio" wire:model='question.{{ $question->id }}'
                        name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]" value="{{ $option->id }}" />
                    {{ $option->option_text }}<br />
                @endforeach
                <br />
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Please share your options data sample.

Comment: this is a link to the video showing the behavior of the loop  https://www.loom.com/share/92fb1d246e0d47a686b1a33e695c1177

Comment: how many option each question? I think your option value should be json data

Comment: each question has its sets of options, depending on how many being set, some questions carry two, while some carry four, while some three.  Can you write the code representation of the json dataset of the options. Thank you

Comment: Do you want an option with the correct answer or something else?
You need JSON data format. Please google it JSON data example

Comment: Seems you don't get what I meant. Please kindly check the video link attached above

Comment: the options of the questions gets shuffled each time I try to click on one

Answer (score 0):

found the fix,
The issue is that the component refreshes whenever I click on an option which causes it to re-render and re-shuffle the questions.
What I did is that I called wire:ignore to allow it not to re-render while I click on an answer. See the code below

```
 <form wire:submit.prevent='lessonTest' action="{{ route('lessons.test', [$lesson->slug]) }}"
            method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div wire:ignore>
                @foreach ($lesson->test->questions->random(4) as $questions)
                    <b>{{ $loop->iteration }}. {{ $questions->question }}</b>
                    <br />
                    @foreach ($questions->options as $option)
                        <input type="radio" wire:model='question.{{ $questions->id }}' name="questions[{{ $questions->id }}]"
                            value="{{ $option->id }}" required />
                        {{ $option->option_text }}<br />
                    @endforeach
                    <br />

                @endforeach
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg refresh" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```